How I can specify the domain in AWS LB for different target groups?
Upon terraform I did:


resource "aws_lb" "test_lb" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]

  enable_deletion_protection = true

  access_logs {
    bucket  = "logs.example.com"
    prefix  = "test-lb"
    enabled = true
  }
}

#Test 1

resource "aws_route53_record" "test_staging_domain" {
  zone_id = "Z09006193JFJXM3FAWH9I"
  name    = "myapp.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [aws_lb.test_lb.dns_name]
}


resource "aws_instance" "test_staging" {
  ami="ami-09d64f47c232fb430"
  instance_type="t3a.micro"
  key_name = "common_ssh"
  count=2
  
  root_block_device {
      volume_size = 30
      volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids=[
    "sg-0304ce47e789c538a"
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test_staging_tg" {
  name     = "test_staging_tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type="instance"
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test_staging-target-group-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.test_staging_lb_listener.arn
  target_id = aws_instance.test_staging.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "test_staging_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.test_lb.arn
  port = 443
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:962331388720:certificate/1cdd1f8c-64d5-4984-a985-133fbe0df5b0"
  alpn_policy = "HTTP2Preferred"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      target_group {
        arn = aws_lb_target_group.test_staging_tg.arn
      }
    }
  }
  
}

#Test 2

resource "aws_route53_record" "test2_staging_domain" {
  zone_id = "Z09006193JFJXM3FAWH9I"
  name    = "myapp2.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [aws_lb.test_lb.dns_name]
}

resource "aws_instance" "test2_staging" {
  ami="ami-09d64f47c232fb430"
  instance_type="t3a.micro"
  key_name = "common_ssh"
  count=2

  root_block_device {
      volume_size = 30
      volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids=[
    "sg-0304ce47e789c538a"
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test2_staging_tg" {
  name     = "test_staging_tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type="instance"
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test2_staging-target-group-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.test2_staging_lb_listener.arn
  target_id = aws_instance.test2_staging.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "test2_staging_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.test_lb.arn
  port = 443
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:962331388720:certificate/1cdd1f8c-64d5-4984-a985-133fbe0df5b0"
  alpn_policy = "HTTP2Preferred"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      target_group {
        arn = aws_lb_target_group.test2_staging_tg.arn
      }
    }
  }
}


With this I try to achieve is the following:

Using a Load balancer I want to direct the approrpiate traffic into specific target group:

The target group test_staging_tg will handle requests for myapp.example.com
The target group test2_staging_tg will handle requests for myapp2.example.com

But how I can do using terraform and hcl to sopeciufy the nessesary domain in me target groups?

You would define multiple load balancer listener rules, one for each domain, with the condition being host_header that matches the domain, and the action being the target group that you want to handle that domain's traffic.

Indeed at previous year (2023) I could define multiple domains upon aws load balancer. But recently I noticed that application load balancers do not allow for defining multiple domains as used to.
The only way to achieve this is:

to use multiple load balancers
Use cloudfront and forward traffic into a different port inyo your load balancer.

For the first one  you can split the terraform definition into 2 files:
test.tf
resource "aws_lb" "test_lb" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]

  enable_deletion_protection = true

  access_logs {
    bucket  = "logs.example.com"
    prefix  = "test-lb"
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "test_staging_domain" {
  zone_id = "Z09006193JFJXM3FAWH9I"
  name    = "myapp.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [aws_lb.test_lb.dns_name]
}


resource "aws_instance" "test_staging" {
  ami="ami-09d64f47c232fb430"
  instance_type="t3a.micro"
  key_name = "common_ssh"
  count=2
  
  root_block_device {
      volume_size = 30
      volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids=[
    "sg-0304ce47e789c538a"
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test_staging_tg" {
  name     = "test_staging_tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type="instance"
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test_staging-target-group-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.test_staging_lb_listener.arn
  target_id = aws_instance.test_staging.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "test_staging_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.test_lb.arn
  port = 443
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:962331388720:certificate/1cdd1f8c-64d5-4984-a985-133fbe0df5b0"
  alpn_policy = "HTTP2Preferred"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      target_group {
        arn = aws_lb_target_group.test_staging_tg.arn
      }
    }
  }
  
}

And test2.tf:
resource "aws_lb" "test2_lb" {
  name               = "test2-lb-tf"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]

  enable_deletion_protection = true

  access_logs {
    bucket  = "logs.example.com"
    prefix  = "test-lb"
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "test2_staging_domain" {
  zone_id = "Z09006193JFJXM3FAWH9I"
  name    = "myapp2.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [aws_lb.test2_lb.dns_name]
}

resource "aws_instance" "test2_staging" {
  ami="ami-09d64f47c232fb430"
  instance_type="t3a.micro"
  key_name = "common_ssh"
  count=2

  root_block_device {
      volume_size = 30
      volume_type = "gp3"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids=[
    "sg-0304ce47e789c538a"
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test2_staging_tg" {
  name     = "test_staging_tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type="instance"
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test2_staging-target-group-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.test2_staging_lb_listener.arn
  target_id = aws_instance.test2_staging.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "test2_staging_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.test2_lb.arn
  port = 443
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:962331388720:certificate/1cdd1f8c-64d5-4984-a985-133fbe0df5b0"
  alpn_policy = "HTTP2Preferred"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      target_group {
        arn = aws_lb_target_group.test2_staging_tg.arn
      }
    }
  }
}

As you can see there are 2 Load balancer rewwsources (thus 2 load balancers as well):

test_lb
test2_lb

Resolving its own domain respectively.

"Indeed at previous year (2023) I could define multiple domains upon aws load balancer. But recently I noticed that application load balancers do not allow for defining multiple domains as used to."
That is completely incorrect
